# How to swap between languages in Dialogflow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, chatbot, google-hangouts

I have a multilanguage agent which is integrated with Hangouts chat and Google Cloud Platform. Do you know any easy way to switch languages during conversation? Fe. at the beginning of talk, you can choose your default language for this session? Or maybe you have any other ideas how to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to write intent in different language? Or do you want to switch at the runtime?

Comment: Want to switch at the runtime. I have already added some intents in English and Polish.

Comment: I'm not enough expert for posting an answer, but in my test (with Google Assistant) the runtime is handle automatically. Contact the agent in one of supported languages, it will answer you in the language defined by your runner (In my case, Google assistant, but I guess it's the same thing with Hangout: it will answer in the default language of Hangout). Is the intended behaviour? If not, can you describe more your use case?